# How to Pass a DriveFile as a Common File?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I asked this question with the purpose of clarifying my doubt that is: How to pass DriveFile as a common file? I explain that I want to be layers that a file that is in the Google Drive cloud be executed by the android system as a common file, ie: transform a drivefile into a file, but without activating a copy of delay and delay Execution Of My application, in what I say is that I want to make a file as a bridge that accesses the data from DriveFile, but without copying them, which the file can read and write to the DriveFile. thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: I do not actually have any code related to this topic for the reason that I asked this question, to get information to help me work on the topic. Thanks for the correction I will use in my next questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to visit [Introduction to the Google Drive Android API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro) wherein it was stated that,

> The file contains a reference to the contents of the file, encapsulated in the DriveContents class, which provides access to read and write the underlying data. Access the contents using the `DriveFile.open` method.

For more information, see [Working with File Contents](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/folders).

Hope that helps!